# MongoDB aggregation date query

Tags: aggregation-framework

Can someone help me with the query for getting the count of bal array by date > 2015-08-02  and by date < 2016-05-02?

My collection:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "a" : "NA",
    "b" : "HXYZ",
    "c" : "12345",
    "d" : "AA"
},


   "bal" : [
 {
        "type" : "E",
        "date" : "2015-08-02"

},

{
        "type" : "E",
        "date" : "2017-08-01"


},
 {
        "type" : "E",
        "date" : "2016-07-07"


}
```

]
 }

I have tried the below query,

```
db.getCollection(bal).aggregate([
{$match:{
        "_id_a" : "NA"
        }
    },

{
    $project: {
        "bal": 1, 
            lessThanDate: {
            $cond: [ {$lt:["$bal.date","2016-05-02"]}, 3, 0]
        },
        moreThanDate: {
            $cond: [ {$gt:["$bal.date","2015-08-02"]}, 4, 0]
        }  
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$bal",
        countSmaller: { $sum: "$lessThanDate" },
        countBigger: { $sum: "$moreThanDate" }
    }
}
 ])
```

The query is not running as expected.

The expected result should be bal array count as 1.

Please help me with the query since am new to mongodb. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) can help here to pick out the `bal` values based on different buckets of conditions

```
var maxDate = '2016-05-02';
var minDate = '2015-08-02';

db.getCollection('bal').aggregate([
{ $match: { '_id.a': 'NA' }},
{ $facet: {
    'balancesBelowMax': [
        { $unwind: '$bal'},
        { $match: {'bal.date': {$lte: maxDate}}}
    ],
    'balancesAboveMax': [
        { $unwind: '$bal'},
        { $match: {'bal.date': {$gte: minDate}}}
    ],
}},
{ $project: { balancesBelowMax: {$size: '$balancesBelowMax'}, balancesAboveMax: {$size: '$balancesBelowMax'} }}
])
```

Comment: how do I get sum of records greater than specific date and less than specific date

Comment: The query I posted will get the records counts of those above the date and those below the specified dates. What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a couple of changes in your query, it can be solved using $unwind on the nested array.

```
db.getCollection("temp").aggregate([
{ "$unwind": "$bal"},
{$match:{
    "_id.a" : "NA"
    }
},

{
$project: {
    "bal": 1, 
    lessThanDate: {
        $cond: [ {$lt:["$bal.date",ISODate("2016-05-02")]}, 1, 0]
    },
    moreThanDate: {
        $cond: [ {$gt:["$bal.date",ISODate("2015-08-02")]}, 1, 0]
    }
}
},
{
$group: {
    _id: "$bal.type",
    countSmaller: { $sum: "$lessThanDate" },
    countBigger: { $sum: "$moreThanDate" }
}
}
])
```

I have modified following things:-

1. Using ISODate for dates instead of String(**you can use new Date() if you 
   have to use String as Date value instead of ISODate()**)
2. Changing match condition from **"_id_a" : "NA"** to **"_id.a" : "NA"**
3. Grouping on bal.type as _id(you can have other field as required)
4. Using $unwind

You can read more about $unwind [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html)